# AspNetCore.SignalR: 'IClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeAsync'

Tags: signalr-hub

I have successfully integrated SignalR.AspNetCore into my AbpZero template. everything works fine. However when I tried to add a hub into my application like what has been described in the [document](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration), I am getting the following error on

```
public async Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
}
```

> Error CS1061  'IClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeAsync' and no extension method 'InvokeAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IClientProxy' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using SendAsync() worked for me.  I am using this package:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview2-30138" />`  The reason I am using it is because when I added the new client to my Angular project, that is the package npm served.  The packages have to match at this time.